# mount:can't read proc/mounts

Tags: 12.04, installation, wubi, mount, proc

I've installed Ubuntu, but when it is loading it gives following error:

```
mount:can't read proc/mounts. Can't fount such file or directory
```

However, OS continues loading but when I try to enter system using my login/password, which I entered during installation, it fails to login.

Does someone know what is problem here?
I've tried reinstall ubuntu several times, but problem still occurs.

*Medium from I installed: Windows 7.
Installed Ubuntu with **wubi**, where I chose separate disk G(NTFS file format), set installation size: 18GB, chose Ubuntu in dropdownlist, language English(GB) and set username and password.*

Comment: Added answer for your question

Comment: have you try to format the / partition of the disk G in EXT?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a caused by running an out of date `wubi.exe` from 12.04 or 12.04.1 (refer to bug [Wubi 12.04 installs development release](https://bugs.launchpad.net/wubi/+bug/1152708)). Because the Wubi.exe is out of date it tries to download the development release wubi disk image. These are no longer created, but there is still a broken one from the 13.04 development release sitting out there, so it gets downloaded.

You need to get the latest Wubi for 12.04.2 from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/wubi.exe

Or the 12.10 Wubi from here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.10/wubi.exe

There is also a 13.04 Wubi here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/wubi.exe

Any of these will work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Wubi installation folder

```
C:\ubuntu\install
```

open file

```
wubildr-disk.cfg
```

The content is:

```
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
search --set=diskroot -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $diskroot
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

Change it to this:

```
loopback loop0 /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
set root=(loop0)
search --set=diskroot -f -n /ubuntu/disks/root.disk
probe --set=diskuuid -u $diskroot
linux /vmlinuz root=UUID=$diskuuid loop=/ubuntu/disks/root.disk preseed/file=/ubuntu/install/preseed.cfg wubi-diskimage ro quiet splash **single**
initrd /initrd.img
boot
```

That single word should be in same line and that is the only change

Then reboot your computer, and choose Ubuntu and it will boot into single user root mode

Create and user with command

```
adduser steve
```

and then add the user in sudo group

```
usermod -G sudo steve
```

Then type `reboot`

Go to windows and restore that `wubildr-disk.cfg` file to original version without the word single

reboot into Ubuntu and you will have steve user available to login from the login prompt.