# Cannot login using my Administrator account after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: installation, 13.10, login, administrator

I've upgraded from Ubuntu 11.10 to Ubuntu 13.10. At the end of installation, a message showed that there are some softwares that can't be installed and they must be manually installed later.
When the installation finished, I tried to login with my Administrator account (with CORRECT password), but I couldn't. I had to login with Guest account.
Anyone has the same problem? what need to do to fix?

Thanks a ton!

Comment: Try to access in X-Terminal pressing `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F1` and try login from there. To switch back press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `F7`

Comment: Hi Rahil. I logged in successfully in X-Terminal. But when i got to Desktop Login, I couldn't login. I create a new Administrator account and using it for now.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem(I guess) since I do not know the exact system configurations pre and post installations I cannot say for sure, but for the similar problem I had I tried the boot-repair tool https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair turns out my hardrive was full. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

[mount:can't read proc/mounts](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283950/mountcant-read-proc-mounts)

It's a problem with the installation package you had.  Had a bad batch, check out the first answer above.